# Facebook returns data on running application multiple times in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to retrieve my facebook pages information.But when I install and run the app first time it gives me.

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

and the next time when I run the application it returns me the correct result.Why this is happening.I want it to return the data the first time i run the app after installation.

Here's my facebook sdk code:

```
private String access_Token="";
private final String APP_ID="MY_APP_ID";
private final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "publish_stream","manage_pages" };
private Bundle params=new Bundle();
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private Facebook mfacebook;
private TextView view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Mozi);

    this.SetConnection();                               //Initialize Fb
    this.getAccessToken();                              //GetAccessToken
    this.CheckSessionExpiry();                          //Create Session with permissions if expired
    this.RetrieveUserPages();
//  this.EnableFBLogout();
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mfacebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
}

private void EnableFBLogout()
{
    mAsyncRunner.logout(getApplicationContext(), new RequestListener() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {

                 String method = "DELETE";
                 Bundle params = new Bundle();
                 /*
                  * this will revoke 'publish_stream' permission
                  * Note: If you don't specify a permission then this will de-authorize the application completely.
                  */
                 params.putString("permission", "publish_stream");
                 mAsyncRunner.request("/me/permissions", params, method,new RequestListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("PerMalform",e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("PerMalform",e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("PerMalform",e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("PerMalform",e.getMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("PerMalform",response);

                    }
                }, null);

          }

          @Override
          public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {}

          @Override
          public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {}
        });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    this.mfacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void getAccessToken()
{
    sharedPrefs= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    if(access_token != null) {
        mfacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    }
    if(expires != 0) {
        mfacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }
}

private void CheckSessionExpiry()
{
      if(!mfacebook.isSessionValid()) {

          mfacebook.authorize(this, this.PERMS , new DialogListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                  editor.putString("access_token", mfacebook.getAccessToken());
                  editor.putLong("access_expires", mfacebook.getAccessExpires());
                  editor.commit();
              }

              @Override
              public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                  Log.e("mozi1",error.toString());
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(DialogError e) {
                  Log.e("mozi2",e.toString());

              }

              @Override
              public void onCancel() { 

                  Log.e("sad","ww");
              }
          });
      }
  }

private void SetConnection()

{
    this.mfacebook=new Facebook(this.APP_ID);
    this.mAsyncRunner=new AsyncFacebookRunner(mfacebook);
}

private void  RetrieveUserPages()
{
    this.params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mfacebook.getAccessToken());
    this.mAsyncRunner.request("me/accounts", this.params, "GET", new RequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Malformed",e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("IO",e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("FNF",e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("FBERR",e.getMessage());

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("responsefromFB",response);       //here the response is an error for the first time and data the second time.
        //  view.setText(response);                             
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mfacebook.authorize()` is asynchronous, which means that code after the `authorize()` method is run even though `authorize()` is not completed.  Because you call `this.RetrieveUserPages()` right after `mfacebook.authorize()`, you are calling

```
    this.params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mfacebook.getAccessToken());
```

*before* `mfacebook.authorize()` has completed, so `mfacebook.getAcessToken()` returns null.

The answer to your issue is to **only** call `this.RetrieveUserPages()` in the `onComplete` method of `mfacebook.authorize()` to ensure that your access token is set before trying to retrieve it.

Let me know if that helps!